# How to call another component function?

Tags: javascript, angular

### HomeComponent-component.ts

```
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

export class HomeComponent OnInit {
price;
 constructor(private router: Router) { }

  async onSubmit(customerData): Promise<any>{
     this.price = customerData.price //price = 2500
  }

  //This is the function help to send the data to another function
  test(){
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state: {price: this.price }};
      this.router.navigate(['price-data'], navigationExtras);//this is going to /price-data component
  }
}
```

### button.component.html

```
<span (click)="test()">Start</span></button>
```

Now when i click the button i want to call the **homecomponent** test() function. As well as both are two component not parent or child. So How is it do?

Comment: There are ways to communicate between components. You can use RxJS observable to emit real-time events or Even Emitter if they are not a parent-child component.

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @Abhinav Kumar Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the HTML where the button component is contained?

To do this, the button component should have an output property

```
@Output("buttonClicked") buttonClicked = new EventEmitter();
```

Then the parent will hook it up like this:

```
<app-button>
(buttonClicked)='onButtonClicked()'
</app-button>
```

And in the parent code there will be this:

```
onButtonClicked(){
  //do something in parent component
}
```

Comment: when using this part
 <app-button>
(buttonClicked)='onButtonClicked()'
</app-button> 
homecomponent display the button. it is in another component